# How to figure out what will be inside the "require" or "require-dev" portion of a composer file?

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, dependency-management

I am writing a *composer file*. There are some dependencies. I am curious how people find out the names of the dependencies. For example one of the dependencies is *ext-imagick*. I know this because one the dependency of my project is *php-imagick* and I asked in SO and someone answered that it should be *ext-imagick*.

How did he figure it out? Is there some kind of library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, PHP imagick extension requirement is defined as `ext-imagick`.

Composer manual [covers ext syntax](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#platform-packages).

You can check extension names against your own PHP installation or [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/extensions.alphabetical.php). Notice that extension page urls contain their identifiers, e.g. 
`http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php` should be referred in Composer as `ext-pdo_mysql` (hyphen in identifier is replaced with underscore).